# How can I send value from a usercontrol to another another one

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two user controls `lblTextbox` (label, textbox and button) and `listUser` (textboxs with a datagridview and button select), where the first one is repeated (button to add how much I want) in a panel that is exists in a form. The button in `lblTextbox` shows the `listUser` to select a user (Id e.g) from it then sending the value to the textbox of `lblTextBox`, and this should happen to each `lbltextbox`.

So how can I pass the selected value from listUser to 
the required `lblTextbox` ?

**This is the panel that exists in home form :**
[image: panel where lblTextbox should appear]

**This is the listUser :**

[image: user control that contain datagrid of users]

**This is the lblTextbox :**

[image: label, textbox and button that shows listuser]

**repeated lblTextbox :**

[image: after pressing "ajouter" add all wanted lblTextbox]